# Extract Value from html website using XPATH, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xpath, web-scraping, xquery

I want to extract: `51.39%`, from this website `www.bayyinah.org`

You can see the text just over the donate button `51.39% of $6 Million`

This is the code that i am using to TRY get that value.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

        let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as NSString!

        do {
            // if encoding is omitted, it defaults to NSUTF8StringEncoding
            let doc = try HTMLDocument(string: urlContent as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            // XPath queries
            for element in doc.xpath("//*[@id='so_far']/text()") {
                print(element)
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
```

}

The result that i am getting is:

```
0%
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to achieve with XPath alone, the HTML itself contains the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="mil"><strong id="so_far">0%</strong> <span class="light">of $6 Million</span></div>
</div>
```

You can see that if you run `curl https://www.bayyinah.org/`

It seems that the web-browser, after retrieving the HTML, subsequently executes some JavaScript which inserts the value.

However if you examine how they do this, you will see that they call this service `https://www.bayyinah.org/api.php?action=get_so_far&clinet_tz=Europe%2FLondon` which returns the following JSON with your answer:

```
{"total_so_far":51.498683333333}
```

So maybe just use their API?

Comment: Perfect love you man. Just a question. Where did you see that service they are using. when i press inspect i cant seem to find what you find

Comment: I used Chrome Developer tools to monitor the network requests they were making.

Comment: https://6sajwt6d6i.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/ramadan_list_new_2019